# Best Practice for Displaying Images on UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data

I am making an app and facing following problem:

I am syncing with server parsing JSON to core data, I have some entities: Photo, Person and Newspaper. I also have 2 UITableViews where I am showing Person's details and News respectively. Images are stored in separate entity called Photo. I am searching for best practice for this approach. I thinks, that NSFetchedResultsController can help , but I might need to override them for respective views. Would it make sense if I take a Photo ID and in UITableCellView for looking up Images. What woud you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a framework like AFNetworking, which adds a category to UIImageView that lets it load the image asynchronously from a given URL. Once the image is loaded asynchronously, you can also cache it to Core Data. If you'd like an even easier approach, I would really recommend using the Sensible TableView framework. The framework will handle everything from fetching the data remotely, displaying it on the table view (including images), and all the Core Data sync. HTH.

Comment: you don't understand, a main problem is to find appropriate photo by id, that person or newspaper has. I doesn't know how to save relations between entities when parse json into core data and then try to display this on view.